# Sorting values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm given the following dataset:

```
df.head()
    Bacteria    Penicilin   Streptomycin    Neomycin
0   Aerobacter aerogenes    870.000 1.00    1.600
1   Brucella abortus    1.000   2.00    0.020
2   Brucella anthracis  0.001   0.01    0.007
3   Diplococcus pneumoniae  0.005   11.00   10.000
4   Escherichia coli    100.000 0.40    0.100
```

I need it to be sorted by bacteria column, so I am trying to use the following command:

```
df.sort_values(by=df['Bacteria'])
```

I am still getting the error. What's wrong with sorting command?

Comment: Use `df.sort_values(by='Bacteria')`

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: Documentation is easier to look at than writing a question here. For your information.

Answer (score 0):

First parameter of sort_values is expected to be a str | list of str by [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

So you should arrange it like `df.sort_values(by='Bacteria')`